# i want to generate a patient details report based on the input (input should be operators like '>','<','=') given by the user

Tags: plsql

//Program to generate a patient details report based on the input given by the //user

```
CREATE or REPLACE  procedure XX_TEAM18_PROc2
    (Admit_date in date,
    Bill_amt in number,
    action in varchar2)
    is
    cursor c 
    is 
    SELECT P.Patient_name,ph.Symptom_issue Symptom,ph.Consulted_dr Doctor,ph.Diagnosis,ph.Bill_Amount 
    FROM
    XX_Patient_Master_Team18 P,XX_Patient_History_Team18 ph
    WHERE

p.Patient_Id=ph.Patient_id
AND
bill_amount action bill_amount;
rec c%rowtype;
cursor c1
 is
SELECT P.Patient_name,ph.Symptom_issue Symptom,ph.Consulted_dr Doctor,ph.Diagnosis,ph.Admitted_date Admitted_date
FROM
XX_Patient_Master_Team18 P,XX_Patient_History_Team18 ph
WHERE
p.Patient_Id=ph.Patient_id 
AND
Admitted_date action admit_date ;

rec1 c1%rowtype;
begin
open c;
dbms_output.put_line('  records belongs to '||Bill_Amt);
fetch c into rec ;
 loop
exit when c%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(rec.Symptom||' '||rec. Doctor||' '||rec.Diagnosis||' '||rec.bill_Amount);
end loop;
close c;
 open c1;
   dbms_output.put_line('  records belongs to given '||Admit_date);
fetch c1 into rec1 ;
loop
exit when c1%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(rec1.Symptom||' '||rec1.Doctor||' '||rec1.Diagnosis||' '||rec1.Admitted_date);
end loop;
close c1;
end ;
```

Comment: What is the question you are having problems with?

Comment: while compilling this code it is giving invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0):

You must use dynamic SQL as parameter `action` cannot be used in a fixed SQL statement within PL/SQL. Parameters can only be used as substitution values, not as column names or operators unless you are using dynamic SQL.

You will need to create a varchar2 variable to hold the SQL statement, then use the DBMS_SQL package to create the cursor. DBMS_SQL has pretty good documentation within it, don't forget to close the cursor when you are done using it.

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for all your suggestions...i figured out it  based on your suggestions